# Copy . . in dockerfile

Tags: docker, copy

I understand that `COPY` can copy files from source folder to destination, but what is purpose of `COPY . .`?

For [example](https://medium.com/the-code-review/docker-copy-dockerfile-best-practices-503704bee69f):

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
CMD ["./your-daemon-or-script.rb"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will copy the current working directory of your local machine into the current working directory of the container.

Answer (score 1):

See the WORKDIR

This command will copy all the content of the parent directory in which your dockerfile resides(contents of your machine) to the location of the WORKDIR in your container.

Answer (score 1):

The `COPY` instruction copies files from the **build context** to the container filesystem.

The initial arguments are relative paths from the build context, and the last argument is a relative path from `WORKDIR` or an absolute path.

So `COPY . .` copies the entire build context to the container's `WORKDIR` (the default workdir is `/`).

```bash
# Docker build defines the context to use

docker build . # will copy the working directory to WORKDIR
docker build ./src # will copy the src folder to WORKDIR
```